# How to install 'wget' on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, docker, wget

I read the documentation of `wget` but did not understand how to download the package.Is there any way (command) to download the package using the terminal on Ubuntu inside a Docker container?

Comment: There is nothing to "download" ... `wget` is already installed ... it is included in all Ubuntu systems. :)

Comment: Did you try using it?

Comment: No it isn't there(/usr/bin) in my ubuntu system.

Comment: What flavour of Ubuntu did you install?

Comment: This is relevant to docker

Comment: Highly relevant to Docker; agreed with Isaac.  `wget` is **not** installed in `ubuntu:latest`.  Voting to reopen (or I would if I had enough reputation).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885137/how-to-run-wget-inside-ubuntu-docker-image

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Please just run this from the terminal if its not there for some reason:

```
sudo apt install wget
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

Comment: This command easily installed the package . thankyou